# C++ vector class definition

Tags: c++

I'm only beginning in C++ and I'm struggling to understand some code from a custom vector class in an article I'm working through. The author writes it as:

```
class vec3
{
 public:
  vec3() {}
  vec3(float e0, float e1, float e2)
  {
    e[0] = e0;
    e[1] = e1;
    e[2] = e2;
  }

(...)
```

But so far I've only seen class definitions where the types of data it holds are defined, such as:

```
class vec3
{
 public:
  float m_x;
  float m_y;
  float m_z;

  vec3(float x, float y, float z) : m_x(x), m_y(y), m_z(z)
  {}
```

My guess was that the code in the article is creating an empty vector which it then populates with floats or there was something assumed in the definition. Is this just a syntax difference or is there something more fundamental that I'm missing? Apologies for what seems like a basic question but I couldn't find any similar questions. . . it might be too basic for that! But I just wanted to understand it before I moved on.

Thanks,
Paddy

Comment: `e` must be defined somewhere in the class. Please add that.

Comment: Yep you're completely  right, I found it right down the bottom of the class definition. It defines e as just a float array. Is it normal that it would be after all of the forward declarations of overloaded operators and things or does it not really matter?

Comment: e is an `std::array` or C-style array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you've posted, you are correct that there is no declaration for the variable `e` anywhere. I'm not sure if this is because you didn't post that part of the code from the book, or if the book omitted that for brevity.

Without knowing what the book author was meaning by `e`, I don't want to suggest a completion of the code. There are several things that `e` could be declared as that would be compatible with the code you've posted.

Comment: Ahhhhh  yep you're totally right. There were a bunch of overloaded operators after this and some other functions, then at the very bottom of all that a:
    float e[3];

I just needed to do some more hunting! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> It defines `e` as just a float array [`e[3]`].

With this information added, then there is no relevant difference between three separate members and an array. In the end, both variants will require the same amount of memory, and in most cases, the (optimised!) code generated by the compiler will be exactly the same:

```
float getY()
{
    return m_y;
    // will result in address of object + offset to m_y
}

float getY()
{
    return e[1];
    // will result in address of object + offset to e + offset to second element
    // as both offsets are constant, they will be joined to one single summand
    // and we are back at first variant...
}
```

One of the few things you can do with arrays but not with separate members is having a loop, such as the following:

```
float magnitude()
{
    float sum = 0.0F;
    for(auto f : e)
        sum += f*f;
    return sqrtf(sum);
}
```

However, for such short loops, loop unrolling is pretty likely, and the code generated again is with high probability equivalent to the separate member variant:

```
float magnitude()
{
    return sqrtf(m_x * m_x + m_y * m_y + m_z * m_z);
}
```

With an array, you could pass all three members in one single parameter to other functions (as pointer to first element), with separate members, you'd have to pass all of them separately (well, there are ways around, but they either require extra effort or are *"dirty"*...).